# What about Tor light?

Tags: relays, performance, speed

Recently unscrupulous marketers in the U.S. were allowed to collect data from all their customers and resell that data. That's why I'm using Tor for pretty much everything I do.

However, I only need a light type of privacy. In my case my data doesn't have to go from The Netherlands to Canada and from there to Germany (and back).

Would it be a good idea to introduce a light version of Tor? My data would only go to one foreign IP address (and back).

The advantage would be that Tor light should work faster since my data only needs to go to one foreign IP address. Another advantage would be that there's less Internet traffic as well, also because my data doesn't have to visit three countries before getting where it should be.

I imagine that, when installing Tor, users could choose whether or not to use Tor light, but that that choice could be changed later in the settings.

Any reactions?

Comment: The system you just described already exists; it is called a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

## This is not what Tor is about.

Going only through 1 IP is **not** secure at all. This IP could capture
all of your in-coming and out-coming traffic easily.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikileaks.org](https://www.wikileaks.org/w/images/c/ca/How_Tor_Works_2.png))</sub>

As with Tor, you traffic goes through 3 different servers. It's greatly saves your privacy.

But if you don't care about your privacy, you could use any public proxy.
I'm not going to tell you how to find them. Just Google it.